# Micro F1 score in Scikit-Learn with Class imbalance

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

I have some class imbalance and a simple baseline classifier that assigns the majority class to every sample:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix

y_true = [0,0,0,1]
y_pred = [0,0,0,0]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

This yields

> [[3, 0],
>
> [1, 0]]

This means TP=3, FP=1, FN=0.

So far, so good.  Now I want to calculate the micro average of precision and recall.

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro') # yields 0.75
recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro') # yields 0.75
```

I am Ok with the precision, but why is recall not 1.0? How can they ever be the same in this example, given that FP > 0 and FN == 0? I know it must have to do with the micro averaging, but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its because of micro-averaging. See the [documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification) to know how its calculated:

> Note that if all labels are included, “micro”-averaging in a
>   multiclass setting will produce precision, recall and f-score that are all
>   **identical to accuracy**.

As you can see in the above linked page, both precision and recall are defined as:
 [image]

where R(y, y-hat) is:

[image]

So in your case, Recall-micro will be calculated as

```
R = number of correct predictions / total predictions = 3/4 = 0.75
```

Comment: Thanks. The paragraph you linked is weird though. The sentence "Note that if all labels are included, “micro”-averaging in a multiclass setting will produce precision, recall and that are all identical to accuracy" is in line with what you say, but that paragraph does not say what A and B actually are, and weirdly, it defines y-hat as the set of true labels and y as the set of predicted labels, which is unconventional, no? My conclusion is to not use micro-averaging for binary classification and to think some more about this.

Comment: Ah, forget the thing I said about A, B not being defined, I get it. But too late to edit my comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Toby Yes, that is unconventional. But all the following things match with this, so no worries. If you want, you may put an issue regarding this usage on [scikit-learn github page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues)